# Number of CPU/Cores in Perl

Tags: perl

How to get number of CPU or Cores in Perl. I want this,  to decide,  creating number of threads dynamically. Below I have created 3 threads. But I want to create threads based on number of cores in that machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore;

my $semaphore = Thread::Semaphore->new();`enter code here`
my $cur_dir   = "D:\\qout";
opendir( CURDIR, "$cur_dir" );
my @file_list : shared = readdir(CURDIR);
closedir(CURDIR);


$thr1 = threads->create( \&changemode, \@file_list, "th1" );
$thr2 = threads->create( \&changemode, \@file_list, "th2" );
$thr3 = threads->create( \&changemode, \@file_list, "th3" );

sub &changemode {

    my ($file_list) = shift;
    my ($message)   = shift;
    my ($i)         = shift;
    while (@{$file_list}) {
        my $fname;
        $semaphore->down();
        if (@{$file_list}) {
            $fname = shift(@{$file_list});
        }
        $semaphore->up();
        print("$message got access of $fname\n");
        system ("csh -fc \"chmod +w $fname\"");
        #sleep (2);
    }
}


$thr1->join();

$thr2->join();

$thr3->join();
```

Comment: As an aside: (1) *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`. The `warnings` module is superior to the `-w` switch. (2) Use a `Thread::Queue` instead of protecting an array with a semaphore. (3) You can't declare a sub like `sub &foo { ... }`. It is `sub foo { ... }`. (4) The `$fname` can be `undef`. You don't account for this when printing it out and executing the `csh`.

Answer (score 15):

Check out the CPAN modules such as [Sys::Info::Device::CPU](http://search.cpan.org/~burak/Sys-Info-Base-0.7802/lib/Sys/Info/Device/CPU.pm)

```
   use Sys::Info;
   use Sys::Info::Constants qw( :device_cpu );
   my $info = Sys::Info->new;
   my $cpu  = $info->device( CPU => %options );

   printf "CPU: %s\n", scalar($cpu->identify)  || 'N/A';
   printf "CPU speed is %s MHz\n", $cpu->speed || 'N/A';
   printf "There are %d CPUs\n"  , $cpu->count || 1;
   printf "CPU load: %s\n"       , $cpu->load  || 0;
```

Answer (score 7):

Old question but here is how I tell the number of CPUs on my linux server:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
chomp(my $cpu_count = `grep -c -P '^processor\\s+:' /proc/cpuinfo`);
print("CPUs: $cpu_count\n");
```

This only works in linux/cygwin. On the bright side this solution doesn't need any extra perl modules installed.

**Edit:**
Barak Dagan suggested a "perl only" solution (I haven't tested it):

```
open my $handle, "/proc/cpuinfo" or die "Can't open cpuinfo: $!\n";
printf "CPUs: %d\n", scalar (map /^processor/, <$handle>) ; 
close $handle;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `getNumCpus` method of `Sys::CpuAffinity` works on many different operating systems and configurations.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for windows-based users who cannot use *Sys::Info* or *Sys::CpuAffinity*:

```
my $numberofcores = $ENV{"NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tight version I am using:

```
use Path::Tiny;
sub getProcessors {
    my @cpuinfo = split "\n", path("/proc/cpuinfo")->slurp_utf8();
    return scalar (map /^processor/, @cpuinfo) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems $ENV{NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS} works nicely for Windows, but I was looking for a Perl one-liner which works on Linux and Cygwin too, which does not call external executables. Unfortunately I do not have Sys::* packages and I cannot install them.

I started with [getconf(1)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/getconf/). It has shows to condfiguration variables: `_NPROCESSORS_CONF` and `_NPROCESSORS_ONLN`. Using [strace(1)](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-strace/) on getconf(1) (`strace -o s.log getconf -a`) it turned out that these information is grubbed using `/sys/devices/system/cpu` path. This dir has `cpu[0-9]+` like sub-dirs, which makes the life a bit complicated. So I returned to the well known `/proc/cpuinfo` and this is the one-liner:

```
my $cpus = do { local @ARGV='/proc/cpuinfo'; grep /^processor\s+:/, <>;};
```

Maybe this could be extended to get the number of online cores, but it is sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but I recently wrote this and it seems to work well...

```
sub getCoreCount {
  my $cpucount = 0;
  open(my $CPUINFO, "<", "/proc/cpuinfo") or die $!;


  while (my $line = <$CPUINFO>) {
    if ($line =~ /^processor/) {
      $cpucount++;
    }
  }

  close $CPUINFO;
  return $cpucount;
}

print "CPUs: ".getCoreCount()."\n";
```

for OS X/macOS I have this https://gist.github.com/ablakely/4328790d106ae448885fe8949f5f4301